# CORS blocking my node server from react app localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, cors

Tried everything I could find on here in regards to setting up cors for my node server. Tried aliasing my localhost and that doesn't seem to work either. Also tried using the CORS unblock extension.

> error: localhost/:1       Access to fetch at
> 'http://localhost:8080/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
> :8080/api/login:1  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

im trying to use magic link authentication in my react app. I got this POST request being made to my node server

```
 const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + didToken,
    },
  });
```

my server code is

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Magic } = require('@magic-sdk/admin');
require('dotenv').config();
 
const app = express()
const magic = new Magic(process.env.MAGIC_SECRET_KEY);


app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "not found" }));
// Allow requests from client-side
app.use(cors({origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL})); 

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.sendStatus(200);
  next();
});

app.post('api/login', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("login fired")
  try {
    const didToken = req.headers.authorization.substr(7);
    await magic.token.validate(didToken);
    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = app
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: The error was actually to do with node server setup not really cors. Jst it was effecting cors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(cors({origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL}));
```

I'd be curious what this URL is. If you want an open CORS policy you don't need to set anything any there.

Put a "/" in front of this route

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
```

I was able to reproduce your problem locally and this server setup worked for me to fix it.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("login fired");
  try {
    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: still gives me the same error. The url in the .env is http://localhost:3000/
I think it has something to do with the type of data being requested? Not sure what im setting wrong. All examples just show setting origin to client url

Comment: try removing this 
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "not found" }));

Comment: Took that out in my test since adding the "/" fixed it. It needs to be after the cors setup if you keep it

Comment: ahh yes that was it.. Was so confused why it wasn't working.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the proxy configuration to divert all the unknown requests to a particular address. In the package.json, just add in the first line -

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

Now, when calling APIs, just use the endpoints like -

```
const res = await fetch(`/api/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + didToken,
    },
  });
```